# I am getting - java.io.IOException cannot be resolved error though importing the IO

Tags: java

```
// Using a do-while to process a menu selection.

public class Menu {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws java.io.IOException {
        char choice;

        do {
            System.out.println("Help on: ");
            System.out.println("  1. if");
            System.out.println("  2. switch");
            System.out.println("  3. while");
            System.out.println("  4. do-while");
            System.out.println("  5. for\n");
            System.out.println("Choose one: ");
            choice = (char) System.in.read();
        } while (choice < '1' || choice > '5');

        System.out.println("\n");

        switch (choice) {
            case '1':
                System.out.println("The if:\n");
                System.out.println("if(condition) statement;");
                System.out.println("else statement;");
            case '2':
                System.out.println("The switch:\n");
                System.out.println("switch(expression) {");
                System.out.println(" case constant:");
                System.out.println("   statement sequence");
                System.out.println("   break;");
                System.out.println("  //...");
                System.out.println("}");
                break;
            case '3':
                System.out.println("The while:\n");
                System.out.println("while(condition) statement;");
                break;
            case '4':
                System.out.println("The do-while:\n");
                System.out.println("do {");
                System.out.println("  statement;");
                System.out.println("} while (condition);");
                break;
            case '5':
                System.out.println("The for:\n");
                System.out.println("for(initialization; condition; iteration)");
                System.out.println(" statement;");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this program in Eclipse IDE I get this error

```
Exception in thread “main” java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
java.io.IOException cannot be resolved to a type  at Menu.main(Menu.java:3)
```

I have rebuilt the project, cleaned it several times, refreshed  still no luck..... :-(

Comment: I ran your code in netbeans 8 and works perfectly. :)

Comment: Sounds like your project is missing the standard library... Right-click project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path... -> Libraries Tab. Make sure JRE System Library is listed.

Comment: @Jyro117 why you believe that? do not you see he provide the java.io.IOException when it declares the main method?

Comment: java.io.IOException is auto-imported, the only reason it cannot be found is if the compiler cannot find the JRE library.

Comment: Thank you friends for your Replies.......

Answer (score 1):

The code you provided here works perfectly.

This error happens when you use Eclipse as IDE and try to run code that doesn't even compile. Check your Problems view in Eclipse, and fix the compilation errors before executing the application.

Comment: where is your source? how this is the answer?

Comment: The source being: Me running your code in Eclipse and getting the expected output. You have something wrong in your set-up of eclipse. Fix that...

Answer (score 1):

the ioexcpetion is in rt.jar which should already be included in your jdk lib. Just make sure your project build path include your jdk or you can just include rt.jar in your build path